# How Can I Change TableView Header Button Image On Click. Need code in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code, just added the image but not changing when hit the button.
Please suggest a working code.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    
    const CGRect fr = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 40.0 );
    btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:fr];
     UIImageView *imgArrow = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(380, 2.5, 25, 25)];
     imgArrow.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.jpeg"];
    [btn setTitle:[self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    btn.contentHorizontalAlignment =UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
     [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    
     [btn setTag:section];
     [btn addSubview:imgArrow];
 
     [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(sectionOpenToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    
return btn;
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for `sectionOpenToggle:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, buttons already have an image view that you can use, so don't do this:

```
[btn addSubview:imgArrow];
```

Instead, do this:

```
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then, in your `sectionOpenToggle` method (assuming it looks like this), change the image:

```
- (void)sectionOpenToggle:(UIButton *)sender {
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"other-arrow.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // whatever else you want to do
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much too helping me.
Try this method also, it 100% works.

-(void)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
 UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

 if( [[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.png"]])
    {
       [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"minus.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       // other statements
    }
 else
   {
       [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       // other statements
   }
}